# How to set number of calls of the function scheduled by LoopingCall?

Tags: python, twisted

Here is the skeleton of the code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

def do_something():
    print "Doing something..."

def process_result():
    print "Processing result..."

def loop():
    LoopingCall(do_something).start(1)

reactor.callWhenRunning(loop)
reactor.run()
```

In my code I want to run `do_something` for 100 times, and after that I will call `process_result` to do what its name indicates.

In the documentation I found a [`withCount`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html#withCount), however I was confused about "*which should have occurred since it was last invoked*" and "*The count is normally 1*" in it. (Using `LoopingCall` to call a function once? What's the point? I think I misunderstood it but what is the correct explanation?)

I'd like to know: is `withCount` the correct thing to use? If yes, can someone provide a concrete example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`withCount` gives you useful information when LoopingCall misses iterations. For example, if the interval is 1, but the function takes 5 seconds, the number of times which the function should have been called would be 5. However, in your example, the function returns almost instantly (and is not a deferred) so it'll be always 1.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

def do_something(count):
    print "Doing something..." + str(count)

def process_result():
    print "Processing result..."

def loop():
    LoopingCall.withCount(do_something).start(1)

reactor.callWhenRunning(loop)
reactor.run()
```

You need to check the number of times that the function has been called and use `lc.stop` when you reach the designated number of times. If you do not want to introduce extra logic in `do_something`, you can make a wrapper class.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

def do_something():
    print "Doing something..."

def process_result():
    print "Processing result..."

def loop():
    LoopingCallWithCounter(5, do_something).lc.start(1)

class LoopingCallWithCounter:
    def __init__(self, count, f, *a, **kw):
        self.i = 0
        def wrapper():
            if self.i >= count:
                self.lc.stop()
            else:
                f(*a, **kw)
                self.i += 1
        self.lc = LoopingCall(wrapper)

reactor.callWhenRunning(loop)
reactor.run()
```

Finally, since `lc.start` returns a deferred when `lc.stop` is called, you can simply use `addCallback(process_result)` to do the post processing. Note that `process_result` should take an argument.

Comment: "withCount is useful only when the function that you wish to call takes longer than the interval." <- not exactly.  There are other reasons LoopingCall may miss iterations.  For example, some _other_ code in your process running for a long time.